# angular 9 Pagination Example Type 'String' is not assignable

Tags: angular, api, pagination, angular9

I am in new in angular 9. I am currently working on angular 9 pagination. Please Help Me..
Angular 9 pagination into HTML table using ngx-pagination.

src/app/app.component.html:20:17 - error TS2322: Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
 'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.

Error image - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcycw.png)

## app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RandomUserService } from './services/random-user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
data:Array<any>
totalRecords:String
page:Number =1

  title = 'pgAng';
  constructor(private randomUser:RandomUserService)
  {
    this.data = new Array<any>()

  }
  ngOnInit() {
  console.log('gggg');
        this.getUsers();
    }
 
  getUsers(){
    this.randomUser.getData().subscribe((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
    this.data = data.results
    this.totalRecords = data.results.length
    console.log(this.page)
    })

  }
}
```

## app.component.html

```html
<!-- npm i ngx-pagination-->
<div class="container">

<button type="button" (click)="getUsers()" class="btn btn-danger">Get Users</button>


<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Gender</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Picture</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of data | paginate: { id: 'listing_pagination',
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: page,
    totalItems: totalRecords }">

  <td>{{user.gender}}</td>
<td>{{user.name.first}}</td>
<td>{{user.name.email}}</td>

<td><img src="{{user.picture.medium}}"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

  <div>
  <pagination-controls  id="listing_pagination" maxSize="5" directionLinks="true" (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
 </div>

</div>
```

## random-user.service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RandomUserService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getData():Observable<any>{
    const url ="https://randomuser.me/api?results=100"
    return this.http.get<any>(url)
  }
}
```

Comment: Well... the error message is pretty clear. It shows the line, the expected type and the received type. Just type `totalRecords` as `number`.

Comment: @developer033 Hi, i have use this code  but not working  data:Array<any>
totalRecords:String
page:Number =1 totalRecords as number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is self-explanatory.

> src/app/app.component.html:20:17 - error TS2322: Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string | number'. Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'. 'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.

This is saying that you have declared a property to be of type `String`, but you are assigning that property to a type that is declared as `string | number`.

In Typescript, the type `string | number` means that you expect the property to be of either type `string` or type `number`.

In Javascript, `String` is a class wrapper around the primitive `string` type. The 2 are not the same. One difference is that `String` uses reference equality, whereas `string` uses value equality.

```js
const s1 = 'abc';
const s2 = 'abc';

const S1 = new String('abc');
const S2 = new String('abc');

console.log('literals match: ', s1 === s2);
console.log('wrappers match: ', S1 === S2);
```

#### The solution

Firstly, it should be noted that this is only a Typescript compile time error. When the code is compiled to Javascript, there are no such thing as declared types.

You should amend your property type declarations to use the primitive types.

```js
totalRecords: number; // change String ->number
page: number = 1;     // change Number -> number. 
                      // Type declaration is redundant when assigning 
                      // from a literal
```

You are setting `totalRecords` from `data.results.length`, so you *know* it's a number. If it were a string you would declare it as a `string`.